# Phonegap and JqueryMobile freeze UI events and functions

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a Phonegap app with JQuery mobile with their latest stable versinos (Phonegap 3 and JQM 1.3.2) for Android platform.

My app downloads feeds from Google Feeds API and saves in a SQLite database. But whenever it starts fetching and saving data from the web (the no of feeds that download at a time can be many), the other functionality such as button events halt and freeze. To be precise the a button that opens and closes a panel does not either open or close the panel until the data fetching stops.

How am I supposed to solve this issue? The performance has dropped drastically due to this issue in my app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general problem in your application how are you handling big data requests. I suggest the following approaches:

- get data asynchron in the background
- maybe prefetching large data
- caching data